# R Colors Fail to Appear on Chart

Tags: r, charts, colors

I am trying to plot a Multivariate Function. However, for some reason, no matter which color I use, the Function always get plotted in black... It seems that the col="lightgreen" parameter does not work. Anybody has clues as to why?

```
# Define Sequences for Multivariate Function
xf3x1 <- seq(-100, 100, length=500)
xf3x2 <- seq(-100, 100, length=500)

# Outer Calculates the Cartesian Product
z <- outer(xf3x1,xf3x2,function(xf3x1,xf3x2) xf3x1*xf3x2)
persp(xf3x1,xf3x2,z,col="lightgreen",theta=30,phi=20, main="Problème 3: Function 3")
```

Comment: Interesting.  Other colors don't work either.  It's always black

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that you have so many facets in a small area, that the facets themselves are small, and the facet borders (black) are too thick resulting in the fill color not showing up.  If you specify that `border = NA`, the surface will show up in the fill color.

```
# Define Sequences for Multivariate Function
xf3x1 <- seq(-100, 100, length=500)
xf3x2 <- seq(-100, 100, length=500)

# Outer Calculates the Cartesian Product
z <- outer(xf3x1,xf3x2,function(xf3x1,xf3x2) xf3x1*xf3x2)
persp(xf3x1,xf3x2,z,col="lightgreen", border = NA, theta=30,phi=20,
  main="Problème 3: Function 3")
```

giving

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to add different colors for different layers so that we see inside of the structure?

Comment: Do you mean creating a surface with colors based on values of the z axis, creating contour slices of the surface, each with a different color, or having multiple surfaces on the same plot, each with a different color?